# I can't uninstall SmartGesture and replace it with new one, that works on Win 10

Tags: windows-10

The problem is that I've updated my Win 8.1 to Win 10 today and my SmartGesture function was off, it did not seem to be working on Win 10. So I deleted it from Control Panel and downloaded the new one, but it gives me this (I can't post picture so I will just write it down).

"Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot be continue. To configure or remove the existing version of this product, use Add/Remove Programs on the Control Panel"

I've tried deleting the drivers with Device Manager but after the restart, they automatically install again and I can't do nothing.

Is there a way to COMPLETELY remove older version, so that I can install new one?

Comment: You should contact Asus support to solve this problem.  You can post the url to the image.

Comment: Exactly today I update the asus smartgestures. New one fails while previous was installed. Control panel / Programs and Features / Asus smart gestures / Uninstall. "No" for reboot. Immediately start installation of new one and it was successfull.

Answer (score 0):

With windows 10 you need to uninstall previous version of smart gestures and install one for windows 10
so

1. Go to Programs and Features find Asus smart gestures uninstall it.(Restart PC)
2. Download new version from asus site [asus drivers](https://www.asus.com/ru/support/Download/3/529/0/4/YVF7HRbsK0Xt6t2h/45/)
3. Install new version restart pc you're done.